# odoo survey questions column format

Tags: odoo

For building odoo website (survey, quiz, feedback, appraisal), how do i break up the questions into few columns format? Every example i see from the internet is just using simple quiz and fulfil their needs. For instance, if i have 10 questions, how do i break them up into 5 apart, side by side? I have no idea where to insert col and colspan if following the survey.template format. Thanks for your advice

```
    <!-- Page 1 -->
    <record model="survey.page" id="quiz_1">
        <field name="title">Quiz</field>
        <field name="survey_id" ref="quiz_main" />
        <field name="sequence">1</field>
        <field name="description">&lt;h3&gt; &lt;/h3&gt;</field>
    </record>
    <record model="survey.question" id="quiz_1_1">
        <field name="page_id" ref="quiz_1" />
        <field name="sequence">1</field>
        <field name="question">Name</field>
        <field name="type">simple_choice</field>
        <field name="display_mode">dropdown</field>
        <field name="constr_mandatory" eval="True" />
    </record> 
    <record model="survey.question" id="quiz_1_2">
        <field name="page_id" ref="quiz_1" />
        <field name="sequence">2</field>
        <field name="question">Identity</field>
        <field name="type">textbox</field>
        <field name="constr_mandatory" eval="True" />
    </record>
```

How do i sort the these 2 questions in a column table/format that they will display side by side instead of a single column?

thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like i have solved my own issue again as well. I have written my own templates into survey.template model to do pure text, line, columns, extra spacing depending on website style conditions, gradient text colours, etc. Then, i realise, survey.survey actually have predefined column code for it. For those interested, it is at

## Display options

```
'column_nb': fields.selection([('12', '1'),('6', '2'),('4', '3'),('3', '4'),('2', '6')],
```

So just initialise it as the same way you do for other settings like 12. There you go. Problem solved!